# How can a I get Metadata ID3 tags from IOS Kaltura playkit

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, id3-tag, kaltura-player

Hi all i have the HLS manifest like the following:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:11045387
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22006,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=3,AVAILNUM=18,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT3M52.717S,DURATION=PT4M0S
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2024-01-29T06:23:56.138Z
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045387.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22006,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=3,AVAILNUM=18,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT3M54.717S,DURATION=PT4M0S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045388.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22006,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=3,AVAILNUM=18,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT3M56.717S,DURATION=PT4M0S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045389.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22006,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=3,AVAILNUM=18,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT3M58.717S,DURATION=PT4M0S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045390.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-IN:ID=22006,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=3,AVAILNUM=18,DURATION=PT4M0S
#EXT-X-CUE-IN:ID=22007,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=3,AVAILNUM=18,DURATION=PT0S
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT:ID=22007,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=3,AVAILNUM=18,DURATION=PT0S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045391.ts
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045392.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT:ID=22008,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,DURATION=PT15S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045393.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22008,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT2S,DURATION=PT15S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045394.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22008,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT4S,DURATION=PT15S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045395.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22008,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT6S,DURATION=PT15S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045396.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22008,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT8S,DURATION=PT15S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045397.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22008,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT10S,DURATION=PT15S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045398.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-SPAN:ID=22008,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,TIMEFROMSIGNAL=PT13.719S,DURATION=PT15S
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045400.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-IN:ID=22008,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,DURATION=PT15S
#EXT-X-CUE-IN:ID=22009,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,DURATION=PT0S
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT:ID=22009,UNIQUEPROGRAMID=6,AVAILNUM=95,DURATION=PT0S
#EXTINF:2.0000,
v4_289_d11045401.ts
```

And i need to detect that #EXT-X-CUE-SPAN   is exist in manifest.    Looks like player should generate the TimedMetadata event but nothing happening during playback Is it possible  to get this tag by another way ?  Thanks a lot!